# How can i get default country store that i setup from admin using javascript in shopify?

Tags: javascript, ajax, themes, shopify

> I have setup 5 country(United States,France,Italy,Spain,Germany) store in my shopify theme for storeswitcher ,My default country store is United States , i want to print default country store united states using javascript code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=shopify+default+country+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<***

Comment: Did you try https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/country

Comment: @mplungjan yes but it is not returning the default country which i set from admin, its returnig other store  country name

Comment: @mplungjan i want to get default store country name that i setup  from admin

Comment: @mplungjan help me please

Comment: @mplungjan is this possible or not ???

Comment: I have no idea. I just try to help you not get banned for asking too many questions. Delete the other one

Comment: @mplungjan okay i have deleted that question